# Particles trajectories in Stern-Gerlach experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, quantum-interpretations, measurement-problem, wave-particle-duality

I red this sentence on "D.J. Griffiths, Introduction to Quantum Mechanics" talking about the using of heavy particles for the experiment.

> "...heavy so we can construct localized wave packets and treat the motion in terms of classical particle trajectories".

Someone can deepen the subject?
I have never used this "approximation" and I do not know on what principles is based on.

Answer (score 2):

Because the mass is large the momentum is large, so the wavelength is short ($\lambda=h/p$ ) and one does not have to consider diffraction and interference as the particles pass through slits in the apparatus.

Alternatively and equivalently:  we measure where the particles are so we have an uncertainty in their momentum, $\Delta p \approx \hbar /\Delta x$, but as the mass is large this only leads to a small uncertainty in their velocity.